# How can I display an Image without downloading it from a url in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

In NodeJS I used package named `node-fetch`, also for taking JSON Response, but how about an Image response? How can I do that? In my current codes, It does only save the image not showing like PIL from python.

```
var tr = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI"

export async function get_image() {
    const get_url = await fetch(tr)
    const image = get_url.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./image.png'))
}

await get_image();
```

Comment: what format do you need the image in? buffer? base64? how will you use the image? we need more information to help understand your question.

Comment: @KyleRifqi the format of the image is png, and about buffer or base64 is maybe base64, and how will I use the image is just like PIL from python (If you ever seen one) `image.show()`

Comment: im not really sure how to display an image in a way similair to `image.show()`. so unless you can use a browser or pass the image data to a python script that will run `image.show()`, i dont think there is a way to do display the image the way you want.

Comment: Hmm maybe if you don't really understand about my questions, my point was Showing an Image from response content without downloading the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an image in Base64 format and save it in a variable using  the [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) module like so:

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const imageURL = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI';

(async ()=>{
    // Get image Buffer from url and convert to Base64
    const image = await axios.get(imageURL, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
    const base64Image = Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64');

    // Do stuff with result...
    console.log(base64Image);
})();

// Or if you prefer, a one liner
(async ()=>{
    const base64Image = Buffer.from((await axios.get(imageURL, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})).data).toString('base64');
})();
```

You can check if it worked by using a website to [decode the base64 string into an image](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter).